# Efficient algorithm to generate undirected graph edges from 3D distribution of nodes based on distance

Tags: graphs

I have a set of nodes where each node $n_i$ is associated with a cartesian coordinate $\vec r_i$ and a radius $\sigma_i$. I want to generate a graph data structure where nodes $n_i$ and $n_j$ are connected by an undirected edge if $|r_{ij}| < \sigma_i + \sigma_j$. This is not my field and I am interested in efficient algorithm/workflow/software suggestions. I am working in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [intersection graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph) of a set of spheres.  The case of 2D disks, all of the same size, is well-studied; its intersection graph is known as a [unit disk graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk_graph), and it has been studied in some depth in the literature.  I don't know if your case has been studied in the literature, but those are some search terms you could use to try to find related work.